# Send message at specific time

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am wanting to send a message to all users logged in on a Windows 2012 R2 Server, but I need to send it at a specific time.

The server restarts at 4am and I want to send message to all users 10 minutes before this happens, because some users are still logged in at this time and I don't want them losing any work.

I won't be at the server at the time to run this so will set up something to run the command at a set time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If someone is logged in at 4 a.m., he's probably going to lose any unsaved work regardless of the message, because he's sleeping.

Comment: If you use the shutdown command (https://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm) you can set the shutdown to start at 4am, every logged-in user will receive a message telling them what time the server will shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Create a scheduled task for 3:50 AM on the specified date that runs a cmd script with the following command:

```
msg * Server is restarting in 10 minutes.
```